# Contador de objetos

Tags: java, clase, objeto, contador

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en java con objetos canciones y albums.

un apartado de ellos debe contarme las canciones y albums (En private) que he creado, para ello:

```
//EN EL OBJETO
public class Song {
    private int cantidadSong;


//CONSTRUCTOR
    public Song(){
        cantidadSong++;
    }


// Contador canciones, get.
    public int getCantidadSong() {
        return cantidadSong;
    }}

//Y EN EL MAIN:
public static void ImpirmirNumero() {
        System.out.println ("Cantidad: " + Song.CantidadSong());
    }
```

Esto no me funciona, y no entiendo el porqué...

El error que me da: The method is undefined for the type Song.

Comment: Creas la clase y luego la cierras y luego pones el constructor los métodos fuera de la clase, ¿Eso no te una idea de porque truena?

Comment: @abrahamhs  No no, perdona, lo he hecho mal, he copiado y pegado mal, ya lo he editado.

Comment: ¿Haríais Static int ContadorSongs?

Comment: el error al parecer es porque estas tratando de llamar a un método llamado "CantidadSong()" que no existe. El único método que tienes es "getCantidadSong()". Tienes un atributo llamado "cantidadSong", el cual en el main al parecer intentas llamarlo con Song.CantidadSong(), cosa que no se puede puesto que, es un atributo y no un método.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a hacer una clase de la siguiente manera:

```
class Song {
    public static int cantidad = 0;
    int cantidadSong;
    String nombreCancion;

    public Song(String nombreCancion) {
        this.nombreCancion = nombreCancion;
        cantidadSong = Song.cantidad++;
    }

    int getCantidadSong() {
        return this.cantidadSong;
    }

    String getNombre(){
        return this.nombreCancion;
    }
    String ImprimirNumero(){
        return "Cantidad total de canciones: "+Song.cantidad;
    }

}
```

Y luego al instanciar los objetos canciones hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
public class TestSong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Song can1 = new Song("No dudaria");
        Song can2 = new Song("Bailar Pegados");
        Song can3 = new Song("La La La"); 

        System.out.println("Nombre Canción: "+can1.getNombre()+" \tNumero Cancion: "+can1.getCantidadSong());
        System.out.println("Nombre Canción: "+can2.getNombre()+" \tNumero Cancion: "+can2.getCantidadSong());
        System.out.println("Nombre Canción: "+can3.getNombre()+" \tNumero Cancion: "+can3.getCantidadSong());
        System.out.println(can1.ImprimirNumero());
    }
}
```

El resultado por consola sería algo similar a lo siguiente:

`Nombre Canción: No dudaria      Numero Cancion: 0
Nombre Canción: Bailar Pegados  Numero Cancion: 1
Nombre Canción: La La La        Numero Cancion: 2
Cantidad total de canciones: 3`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios fallos, te los comento en el código:

```
public class Song {

    private int cantidadSong; // Debería ser static (1)

    public Song(){
        cantidadSong++;
    }


// Contador canciones, get.
    public int getCantidadSong() { // Debería ser static (1b)
        return cantidadSong;
    }

    public static void ImpirmirNumero() {
        // Estás llamando a un método que no existe (2)
        System.out.println ("Cantidad: " + Song.CantidadSong());
    }
}
```

1. Un atributo no estático es un atributo de instancia, se crea uno nuevo para cada objeto creado. Tal y como lo tienes su valor siempre sería 1.

   1b. Al ser este atributo estático, el método que lo acceda debería ser también estático (no pertenece a una instancia). Tal y como está funcionaría pero no es semánticamente correcto.
2. El método para acceder al atributo privado es `getCantidadSong()`, no existe un método `CantidadSong()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Vale ya lo entiendom la última duda, porque debe ser static?

Comment: Como comento en el punto 1, los atributos no estáticos pertenecen a las instancias. Cada objeto Song tendría un atributo cantidadSong que se incrementaría desde 0 hasta 1 al crearlo. Los atributos estáticos pertenecen a la clase, por lo que cada objeto accedería al mismo atributo.